# Hardware requirements for windows store app

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have published a HTML5 Universal app to the Windows Store. Now when I search for my app in store, it lists "keyboard" in hardware requirements.

It says "This app needs additional hardware requirements" when I see it in the Store. Where does it come from? How can I remove it?

Comment: Does your app require a keyboard?

Comment: @CodyGray No it doesn't. I have not written any code requiring keyboard as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an options in the `App Properties` section called `Hardware preferences`.. you can un check the keyboard and it must not be an issue anymore :)

[image: Hardware preferences]